# Group multilanguage Facebook likes

Tags: facebook-like

I,ve got a Webshop which supports multiple languages. 
On my product detail page, users can like products. 
But, the english version of the page has a different url than the dutch version of the page. 
for example: 
en: www.domain.com/en/product
nl: www.domain.com/nl/product
When a user likes the product on the english page, the dutch page has no likes. 
Is there a possibility within the facebook like button to group this likes,
so every version of the page has the same amount of likes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to set the `og:url` property for the different language versions of one product to one URL, f.e. the English version of the product page.